# Фикс вызова категорий WordPress/Woocommerce

Tags: php, html, wordpress, woocommerce

Всем привет! Есть вызов категорий товаров, код прикладываю. С ним получается так, что у каждой категории по-любому есть ul внутри. Даже если он пустой:

```html
<ul>
  <li><a href="#">Категория 1</a>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Подкатегория 1-1</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Подкатегория 1-2</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>

<ul>
  <li><a href="#">Категория 2</a>
    <ul>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Нужно сделать так, чтобы он проверял, если у категории нет подкатегорий, то не делать пустой ul внутри li. То есть вот так:

```html
<ul>
  <li><a href="#">Категория 1</a>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Подкатегория 1-1</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Подкатегория 1-2</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>

<ul>
  <li><a href="#">Категория 2</a></li>
</ul>
```

Вот сам PHP, который вызывает их. Как его дописать, чтобы он проверял наличие подкатегорий? Может кто сталкивался?

```html
<?php 
  $args = array(
    'taxonomy' => 'product_cat',
    'hide_empty' => false,
    'parent'   => 0
  );
  $product_cat = get_terms( $args );

  foreach ($product_cat as $parent_product_cat)
  {

  echo '
    <ul>
      <li><a href="'.get_term_link($parent_product_cat->term_id).'">'.$parent_product_cat->name.'</a>
        <ul>
          ';
  $child_args = array(
    'taxonomy' => 'product_cat',
    'hide_empty' => false,
    'parent'   => $parent_product_cat->term_id
  );
  $child_product_cats = get_terms( $child_args );
  foreach ($child_product_cats as $child_product_cat)
  {
    echo '<li><a href="'.get_term_link($child_product_cat->term_id).'">'.$child_product_cat->name.'</a></li>';
  }

  echo '
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>';
  }
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Просто делайте проверку по подкатегориям до вывода внутреннего

```
  $args = array(
    'taxonomy' => 'product_cat',
    'hide_empty' => false,
    'parent'   => 0
  );
  $product_cat = get_terms( $args );

  foreach ($product_cat as $parent_product_cat)
  {

  echo '
    <ul>
      <li><a href="'.get_term_link($parent_product_cat->term_id).'">'.$parent_product_cat->name.'</a>';
      
            $child_args = array(
                     'taxonomy' => 'product_cat',
                     'hide_empty' => false,
                     'parent'   => $parent_product_cat->term_id
                    );
            $child_product_cats = get_terms( $child_args );
            
            if ($child_product_cats) {
  
                  echo '<ul>';   
                
                  foreach ($child_product_cats as $child_product_cat) {
                            echo '<li><a href="'.get_term_link($child_product_cat->term_id).'">'.$child_product_cat->name.'</a></li>';
                  }

                 echo '</ul>'; 
            }
            
   echo '</li>
    </ul>';
  }
```

Comment: Спасибо огромное, то что нужно!